# Does using singleton pattern will make my application slower if multiple users are working on it simultaneously

Tags: java, spring-boot, singleton, prototype

I am facing trouble understanding use on Singleton. I understand that while using singleton pattern once one instance of a class is created and is shared across all of the users. However won't this make an application slow for users in multiple (say a few thousands of users) are using that resource at a moment?

For eg. If one of my service class "Sendmail" is a singleton, then only one instance of that class will be created in IOC container. Now this instance will be shared with all of the current users using that resource. Now if multiple users try to send emails at a moment, all of the requests will wait in the queue as only one instance of Sendmail is created, won't this make the users wait to send their email? This will be a very poor experience for the users. Same goes with the Database connection. Then why it is recommended to use Singleton over prototype?

Kindly please help me clear my confusion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Singleton pattern does not slow down application. It basically create single object and make it available every time requested.

But when you are taking about multiple user accessing data/resource at same time this is concurrency concept. if you implement some concurrency control techniques then processing of data/resource might slow down.

Note : All depends on developer that how horrible code he/she is writing.

Comment: So if I have thousands of request with each request containing thousands of sql transactions, the user may feel some lagging in the application as only one instance is working on all transactions?

Comment: Consider example:- when request land to your endpoint and enter into critical section which you protecting from multiple thread (using synchronization in java) then another user request will wait to complete first one.

Comment: Yes, If i use synchronization then another user request will wait to complete first one, however while using singleton will context switching will take place? Also  if the application is to be used by the various moment at a time is it wise to use Singleton scoped beans or prototype scoped beans?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not and expert but someone will correct if I'm wrong.
First, Sigleton are one instance for the application. If you lauch your application twice they while work separatly even if they are communicating.
Secondly Sigleton are a patern for devellopement. It dont really affect the performance of your application while compiled.
And lastly few thousand of request at the same time is not very heavy for somthing simple as a connection, it will more block at the communication then at the processing.

Note: Connection to data base are a typical exemple of sigleton. Their is no stupid question but you can guess taht id everyone use it, it's may be an optimised way.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton classes doe not slows down your processing, it simply means that only one instance of the object is created and is made available across threads/classes.

If you are talking about the slow down of the process by having threads waiting to send an email is just because of the concurrency control. If your use case does not have anything to do with the ordering or can simultaneously send the email, then singleton won't create an issue. Having said that, the connector(3rd party API) you are using can slow your process as they are generally written in order to have concurrency control.

But in your case javax mail will not create an issue to send the email. You can blindly use the singleton to wrap the send email feature.